# How to fix ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer vgg16 when using transfer learning with deep learning?

Tags: deep-learning

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer vgg16: expected shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(None, 1, 224, 224)

how to solve the problem?